# Firestore index works as collection and collection group. which is better?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I had to set up an index to enable `orderBy`/`where` in my Firestore query.

I tried `Query Scope = Collection`, and `Query Scope = Collection Group` - Both worked.

Is there a benefit to using one vs. the other, i.e. cost or performance?

Answer (score 1):

The [Query Scope](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview#query_scopes) has nothing to do with cost or performance. As the name says, an index with collection scope and collection group scope will support queries on a single collection and collections with name (collection groups) respectively.

The official descriptions mentioned in the documentation are:

| Scope | Description |
| --- | --- |
| Collection | Cloud Firestore creates indexes with collection scope by default. These indexes support queries that return results from a single collection. |
| Collection Group | A collection group includes all collections with the same collection ID. To run a collection group query that returns filtered or ordered results from a collection group, you must create a corresponding index with collection group scope. |

A [Collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) basically queries through all the collections (usually sub-collections). An example would be a root level collection 'posts' and each document (post) has a sub-collection 'comments'. Using collection group queries you can run queries on 'comments' collection of all posts as they have same collection name/ID.